# Adding Current User's Information to a Post in Phoenix Framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm moving from Rails to Phoenix and running in to an issue that I can't find the answer for.

I've got user authentication set up (by checking for @current_user in a private authenticate function).

I also have a Post model/controller/view (scaffold for those familiar w Rails).

I'd like to automatically fill a Post field with the @current_user ID when the form is submitted (each post will belong to a user) without a form field that the user has to fill in.

In Rails this is pretty straightforward... something like this added to the create action of the post controller works:

```
@post.user = current_user.id
```

How do I do this with the Phoenix Framework/Elixir?

Here's the create action in my PostController

```
  def create(conn, %{"post" => post_params}) do
    changeset = Post.changeset(%Post{}, post_params)

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, _project} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Please check your email inbox.")
        |> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :thanks))
      {:error, changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

Should this type of logic be performed in the controller or the model? or is there a good way to do this in the view (without using a hidden field which isn't secure).

**Solution** (thanks to Gazler):

```
  def create(conn, %{"post" => post_params}) do
    current_user = conn.assigns.current_user
    changeset = Post.changeset(%Post{user_id = current_user.id}, post_params)
    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, _project} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Please check your email inbox.")
        |> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :thanks))
      {:error, changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
current_user = conn.assigns.current_user
changeset = Post.changeset(%Post{user_id: current_user.id}, post_params)
```

Or use [Ecto.build_assoc/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.html#build_assoc/3):

```
current_user = conn.assigns.current_user
changeset = Ecto.build_assoc(current_user, :posts, post_params)
```

This assumes you have `current_user` in your `conn.assigns`.

Comment: Thanks Gazler. I've edited my question - I have a private function that checks for conn.assigns.current_user (and works); however, I'm getting an error saying undefined function current_user. How do I ensure that current_user is in my conn.assigns?

Comment: It looks like you forgot the `current_user = conn.assigns.current_user` (which I only showed in the first example. I have updated the 2nd to also include it). If you don't want to have to call `conn.assigns.current_user` then you may want to have a look at the `overriding :action` section of https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html

Comment: Yes - I did. Makes sense. Thanks for your help!

Comment: cannot `conn.assigns.current_user` be shortened to some shorter name and be accessed from anywhere within the application?